# Перехватить событие back

Tags: android, java

Перехватываю событие  функцией

```
public void onBackPressed() { }
```

на `surfaceView` оно не перехватывает, пытаюсь через

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { }
```

Тоже не реагирует, что посоветуете?

Comment: [Переназначение BackButton](http://hashcode.ru/questions/58385/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-backbutton)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю в каком месте вы пытаетесь обработать ивенты. Нужно в классе активити и если вам нужно предовратить переход на предыдущую активити то это однозначно делается в onKeyDown, например:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Выйти?")
                .setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        finish();
                        return;
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        return;
                    }
                })
                .show();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Черт братюнь ты мне глаза открыл, я не туда ставил этот долбаный онКейДовн, это у меня баг был, а не в способе перехвата.. Спасибо всем!

Comment: баг - это когда работает, но не правильно =) у тебя просто не работало

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего не указали `View.setOnKeyListener(...)` - то есть надо указать объект который будет перехватывать клавиатурный ввод - обычно указывается `View.setOnKeyListener(this)`, тогда требуется чтобы `this` реализовывал интерфейс `View.OnKeyListener`

Answer (score 1):

[How to finish the Activity from inside the surface view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877980/how-to-finish-the-activity-from-inside-the-surface-view)